# css mime type return as text/plain rather than text/css

Tags: mime-types

I am using this code to get the mime type from a given file

```
$finfo = new \finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime  = $finfo->buffer(file_get_contents($file));
```

If I feed it a PHP file then I get

```
text/x-php
```

but if I feed it a CSS file I get

```
text/plain
```

I have been trying to solve this issue to no avail, I have AddType in my Apache to allow for CSS file types.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell Apache to serve files as **text/css** whenever their *extension* is **.css**. The only sane way for your server to differentiate between a style sheet and any other type of text file, is by its file name.

You can do so by editing Apache's *MIME type configuration file*, which is named **mime.types** ( it lives in a different folder depending on your distro, maybe try */etc/apache2* ) to make the following association:

```
text/css                    css
```

Alternately, if you don't have admin access, you can create an **.htaccess** file in your own web root. More info on both methods [here](http://www.hypercosm.com/support/howto6.html)

Hope this helps!

Upon rereading our question, maybe I misunderstood you, and you have already done the steps above?

If so, could you check what your OS is reading the mimetype as? There are appropriiate commands to check mimetype, [over here](http://blog.max.berger.name/2010/01/find-mime-type-for-file.html):

Also, it seems like it would be pragmatic to add a subsequent check to see if the file extension ends with .css. Is there a reason why this won't work?