# CSS nor recognised as CSS file

Tags: html, css, server

After building my web site for a while now, I wanted to see if I could upload it to my domain and see if it was functional from the web.

Now I have this error coming from my css files : 
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.benny-water.com/Mainscss2.css"

I have been googling for 3 hours straight and haven't found a solution. If I understand it is my server (OVH) that is wrongly interpreting the css files as html or text files but I have no idea where to change this.

my  code for the css files looks like this :

```
<head>
    <title> Benny Water </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="Mainscss2.css"> </link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/Css3.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/Grid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ng-href="js/Jportfolio/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ng-href="js/Jportfolio/css/jportilio.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ng-href="js/Jportfolio/css/jportilio_style_default.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Jportfolio/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Jportfolio/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Jportfolio/js/jportilio.js"/>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"/>

</head>
```

thank you for your help :)

Comment: Something must be wrong with your `.htaccess` file

Comment: my .htaccess looks like this,  RewriteEngine on
# not rewrite css, js and images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^abc/(.+)/(.+)/ abc.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]

# rewrite css, js and images, from root
RewriteRule ^abc/[^/]+/[^/]+/(.+)$ $1  [L]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css mime type return as text/plain rather than text/css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782024/css-mime-type-return-as-text-plain-rather-than-text-css)

Comment: I've flagged a duplicate for this. It sounds like a server config issue; if you have access to your server config then you'll be able to follow the instructions. If you don't, then you can configure it locally for your site, but ideally you should be talking to your hosting provider to sort it out.

Comment: @BennyWater — Are you generating your CSS from PHP? My mod_rewrite fu isn't up to decoding your comment.

Comment: *Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "`http://www.benny-water.com/Mainscss2.css`"* — That URL is currently being served with a text/css content type.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your paths there seems to be a mismatch between where your CSS files are located.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="Mainscss2.css"> </link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/Css3.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/Grid.css" />`

The `/style/Css3.css` has a `/` in front of your path, but the `style/Grid.css` doesn't.

Your `Mainscss2.css` link is also closed incorrectly. I would removed `</link>` and close the tag with `/>` instead for consistency in your code.

Comment: This only states the same assumptions as the attempted answer by Nihvel but does not answer the question

Comment: Reason for suggestion the path fix was to make sure they are all correct. 

The file causing the error is no longer accessible at the URL in the description. But usually when the interpreter reads the CSS file and tries to render it. The browser returns the error `MIME type text/html` due to a CSS error somewhere in the file. 

I could help debug the file for errors if still available?

Answer (score -2):

The .css file must go inside the `<head>` tag, while the .js in the `<body>` tag. It is a rule but it obviously work anyway also when they all are inside `<head>` too.

About the path of your .css, are you sure it is correct?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="Mainscss2.css"> </link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/Css3.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/Grid.css" />
```

there are 3 different paths for 3 .css

Use this scheme:

```
/var/www/mywebsite/index.php
/var/www/mywebsite/images/favicon.ico
/var/www/mywebsite/style/css/mytheme.css
/var/www/mywebsite/style/css/images/imagesUsedBymytheme.png
/var/www/mywebsite/style/js/myscript.js
```

of course modify it accordingly, if you are index.php, you would want to link your .css using this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/css/mytheme.css" type="text/css" >
```

EDIT:
`<link>` is a single tag, you can use it as `<link rel="" href"" >`

Comment: Can we please stop downvoting this answer? The code is full of errors. `<script>` wants its closure `</script>` tag. If you close it like `<script />` it will not work. I think you are not able to have your code running because the code is dirty.

Comment: The .css file must go inside the head tag — True, but the question shows it is, so that's irrelevent.

Comment: while the .js in the body tag — False. JS can go in the head.

Comment: About the path of your .css, are you sure it is correct? — The question describes a warning given by the browser. It does not say that CSS isn't being applied. There is nothing to suggest that the path is wrong.

Comment: script wants its closure /script tag. If you close it like script / it will not work. — True, but the question isn't asking about the JS. It is about a warning given by the CSS.

Comment: You're getting downvoted because you've made a lot of comments about the code quality, but haven't identified the cause of the problem, so you haven't managed to answer the question.

Comment: Js CAN go in the head does not mean "js go only in the head". Means that it is better to have the js in the `<body>` rather in the head, even if placing in the head will work too.
Study html, please.

Comment: YOU CAN'T HAVE A WORKING CODE IF YOUR CODE IS FULL OF ERROS: for god's sake. DO what you want. The code will never work if no one respect few simple html rules.

Comment: "Means that it is better to have the js in the body" — No, it doesn't mean that.

Comment: "YOU CAN'T HAVE A WORKING CODE IF YOUR CODE IS FULL OF ERROS" — You can. Browsers are *really* good at error recovery. It isn't a good idea, and you've mentioned a lot of things that should be fixed, but none that appear to actually fix the problem *being asked about*.

Comment: Ok, great. modify a working call to a script: `<script type="text/javascript" src="style/js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>` to this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="style/js/jquery-1.12.4.js" />` prove it in your html page sample with anything that would want jquery to run.
You dumb browser will not fix the error. That is a error.

Comment: The question isn't asking about jQuery not working, it is asking why the server is sending a `Content-Type: text/html` header for a JS file. As I said, you've mentioned a lot of things that should be fixed, but none that appear to fix the problem *being asked about*.

Comment: It is the same! If the code is wrong, the code is wrong. The browser will fix what it can. But when the code is wrong, it will not. PLUS since when we love dirty code? First thing I learnt before coding was typing it clean.
... And then we think why nothing work. Simple. Here's the proof.

Comment: "It is the same!" — No. It is not. They are distinct and unrelated problems.

Comment: "PLUS since when we love dirty code?" — I have said repeatedly that the issues you've pointed out should be fixed … they just aren't related to the problem the question is asking about. (i.e. they belong in comments, not answers)

Comment: It is the same. You can't call a css or a script in a not correct way and wonder why it does not work. PLUS you have never said that. Only pointing that what I say is not related to the problem. Was a answer about changing php.ini for better? NO. The problem is the bad code used.

Comment: "It is the same" — No, it isn't. Different errors are different and have different symptoms.

Comment: "You can't call a css or a script in a not correct way and wonder why it does not work" — There is nothing wrong with how the CSS is being called in the code in the question. (For that matter, if the document is being served as `Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml` then it is completely valid and supported XHTML.)

Comment: "Was a answer about changing php.ini for better?" — There isn't an answer about php.ini, not even a deleted one.

Comment: I am damn tired to play your game. Know what? I am already developing a website, I call everything as it should be called. It works, clean code, responsive. Browser must not correct any error because there aren't and I live happy even with some point less in my account.

Comment: "The problem is the bad code used" — It can't be. Bad HTML cannot give the symptom described in the question.